# Knockout CSS styling, through a function as well as a binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I know that you can use knockout to set the class as per a function return like so;

```
<span data-bind="css: styling()"></span>
```

You can also set them inline with a true/false value.

```
<span data-bind="css: {className: $parent.active() == $data}"></span>
```

Is there a way to do both in the one binding? My example is that I want to return a custom class depending on the type of the item displayed by the span element (there will be many of these) but I also want them to be highlighted if they are selected.

It seems that you cannot use functions on the right hand side of the object, and having two cause the second to overwrite the first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

With this sample you will be able to specify the classes of each item.

**View**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items" >
    <span data-bind="css : $parent.styling($data), text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
var vm = {
    items : ['a','b','c' ],

    styling : function(item ) {
        if(item =='a') return 'active';
        if(item =='b') return 'active bold';
        return '';
    }    
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tNY6/)

---

**Edit:**

@Shadow : You right,  if you pass a value to a computed it is to set (or write) it.

I think this would match your needs.
When on an item the toggle function is called.
Then the active observable will be changed and finally the styling computed.

**JS**

```
var Item =  function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = data;
    self.active = ko.observable(false);
    self.styling = ko.computed(function(item ) {
        if(self.active()) return 'active';
        return '';  
    });
    self.toggle =  function(){
        self.active(!self.active());
    }
};

var vm = {
    items : [new Item('a'),new Item('b'), new Item('c') ]        
};


ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**View**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items" >
    <span data-bind="css : styling, text: name, click : toggle"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tNY6/4/)

Comment: Sortof in the right direction - but in my case the array is full of sub views. This answer would probably work if I could invoke a function in the subview from the parent view... Do you know if you can pass it through?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to work as we aren't using an observable. Which means I cannot track the active item (and thus add the style to it). You cannot pass arguments (to my knowledge) to a ko.computed. Any other ideas?